# Added fragment scrolled down

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have two fragments the first fragment contains list of linear layouts and the whole fragment is in scroll view the second fragment is added and the first is hidden on choosing item from the first.
The problem is the second fragment is created scrolled down if the first fragment was scrolled down. 
I tried the ways to force second fragment to be scrolled to (0,0) but failed.

the code used to add the second fragment

```
public void setActionOnClick(String id) {
     CommentFragment frag = new CommentFragment();
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("id", id);
     bundle.putString("TAG", TAG_NEWS_STORY);
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentTag(TAG_NEWS_STORY);
     frag.setArguments(bundle);
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, 
     android.R.anim.fade_out);
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_content, frag, TAG_NEWS_STORY);
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

on Attach of second fragment the first fragment is hidden.
I don't want to use fragmentTransaction.replace because there are calls to the api which I don't want to reload.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question but. probably your fragment `place_hoder` is inside an scrollview.
just check if `R.id.main_content` is  in a scrollview or not.
you should add the `ScrollView` to the `fragment-layout` instead of instantiating the fragment inside one

Answer (score 0):

Before this:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Add code to remove old fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourOldFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: I don't want to remove old fragment and I doesn't work for me it appears scrolled too.